# Selenium : How can I scroll to an element in an iFrame

Tags: selenium, c#

I have an element that is out of view when I am using Selenium within an iFrame. I have switched the context using

`Driver.SwitchTo.Frame("frame_id")`

and I am able to interact with elements that are visible in the iFrame. However when I need to interact with elements that are inside the frame but out of view I cannot find a way to force the Frame to scroll down.

I have tried running some javascript:
[Scrolling and iframe with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript)

Also tried using the technique described in the following 
[article](http://theautomationtester.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/scroll-down-to-end-of-the-page-in-selenium-web-driver/)

I have tried tabbing on the last visible element to force the frame to scroll down, which works in some cases but I need a more concrete solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get around this issue by creating a static method that scrolls down the page:

```
public class Browser
{
    public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    public static ITargetLocator CurrentFrame { get; private set; }

    public static void SwitchFrame(string frameId)
    {
        CurrentFrame = Driver.SwitchTo();
        CurrentFrame.Frame(frameId);
    }

    public static void ScrollDown()
    {
        CurrentFrame.ActiveElement().SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
        CurrentFrame.ActiveElement().SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Browser.Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
Browser.SwitchFrame("myInnerFrame");
Browser.ScrollDown();
```

I just call the ScrollDown method whenever I know an element is out of view and it does the trick.